# Asp.net MVC web.config Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to ask some config error that i face in my project when i host on iis.first,i created 
sample asp.net mvc application,i didn't change anything of built-in web.config.it's normally work when i run,so,i decided to host on iis7.After that when i run hosted application,it occrus error.i tested on window7 and window2008.both errors are same.

Error Summary
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detail Error Info
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    BeginRequest
Handler Not yet determined
Error Code  0x80070021
Config Error    Configuration section not allowed to be set below application
Config File \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MvcSampleApp\web.config
Requested URL   http://localhost:80/mvcapp/mvcApp
Physical Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MvcSampleApp
Logon Method    Not yet determined
Logon User  Not yet determined

Config Source

```
122:        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
123:        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
124:        <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
```

how i fixed this error?please guide me right way.

regards
Chong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set up your website in a folder rather than as an application - you should be able to change it to an application in IIS manager, or you can move it up a level so that the path is /mvcapp rather than /mvcapp/mvcapp.

Comment: actually,i am not famaliar with hosting and configuration.i tell you what i try.first,i create virtual directory in iis and point to my project folder.And then,i make convert to application.is it right?then i run again,error is still occur but different with previous.

The SessionStateTempDataProvider requires SessionState to be enabled
any idea? thanks

Comment: That one has a more obvious fix- http://computingtech.blogspot.com/2008/07/configuring-session-state-settings-for.html